# Как нарисовать изолинии по точкам на Java?

Tags: java, картография

Есть массив точек (X, Y, Высота(Z)), мне нужно изобразить изолинии по этим точкам, типа вот такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть очень много разных алгоритмов, по ним не совсем понимаю, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие именно операции нужно проделать, чтобы получить изолинии в окне на Java?

У меня есть код триангуляции Делоне, есть реализация алгоритма марширующих квадратов, но я не понимаю, как по моим точкам прорисовать изолинии с помощью данных алгоритмов.

Comment: Изолинии - линии равной высоты, или линии среза  плоскостями высоты. Вам нужно последовательно соединить точки одинаковой высоты, то есть z. Хотя, конечно, надо взглянуть как у вас заданы эти самые точки будущих изолиний

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, а у меня в файле пока что нет одинаковых высот, точки выглядят так: 
<pre>
 
        X                 Y        Высота(Z)     
    -44.876      -0.479      -0.139
</pre>

поэтому, немного не понял, что значит соединить точки одинаковой высоты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После триангуляции у Вас есть набор плоских наклонных треугольников. Заданный уровень (горизонтальная плоскость) может -

- проходить вне (выше или ниже) треугольника,
- пересекать треугольник (в одной точке - вершине, по отрезку внутри треугольника, по стороне треугольника),
- полностью содержать треугольник (если он горизонтальный и лежит на данном уровне).

После анализа каждого уровня для каждого треугольника, у Вас будут отрезки для каждого уровня, которые надо соединить в ломаные или сразу рисовать, если Вас интересует только отрисовка.

---

Изолиния - это линия (возможно, набор линий - замкнутых или нет) пересечения поверхности, заданной Вашим набором точек, и горизонтальной плоскости, проходящей на определенной высоте (уровне). Высоты, соответствующие изолиниям разных уровней, задаются исходя из физического смысла задачи. Если речь идет о изолиниях ландшафта, то они могут идти через каждый метр, пять, десять и т.д., в зависимости от масштаба карты.

Comment: @firuz Не совсем понял вопрос. Добавил объяснение.